# Asp .NET Core Identity Server exclude some urls from login redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have got a simple application using Identity server, Web API and Angular. The issue is with the Identity Server redirection. The goal is to exclude some paths for instance: https://localhost:5000/test from auto redirection to login page without authorization and directly open the Angular component on this url. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: we need to see the controller class for that action

Comment: usually is just about adding "[AllowAnonymous]" to the urls and configuring the routes properly in the startup.cs

Comment: I have already marked the action in the controller with AllowAnonymous attribute but it still redirecting, I think there should be some way to ignore some paths from authorization check and redirection to login page

Comment: Yeah the way is to mark them AllowAnonymous.... You need to post your route configuration from your Startup.cs and your controller code

Answer (score 0):

Your request must be more detailed with a code sample of your controller to reproduce and understand. Maybe you should also specify .NET and IDS4 version, if it is IdentityServer4 ?

Because for an IDS4 and according to the [documentation](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html), you have to choose between different workflow to authenticate. The most common way and the safer one is to use **authorization code**

To find which workflow are supported on your IDS4  call this URL :
**http://YOUR_SEVER/.well-known/openid-configuration**

The login redirection depend on IDS4 setting for a UI behavior, so if you try to call directly your [AllowAnonymous] route with a browser, you will not be redirected normally and get your response directly.